# How can i print new instance in console after creating a post request from django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I post data from Django admin panel. I want to print data always in the console when new instance created from Django admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You can override `save_model` method on admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        print(obj)
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model